# Control PTZ of an IP Camera

Tags: http, soap, ip-camera, onvif

I am building a project using the IP Camera Intelbras 5220 SD IR [Datasheet](http://www.intelbras.com.br/sites/default/files/downloads/datasheet_lancamento_speed_domes_vip_5220_sd_e_vip_5220_sd_ir_site.pdf).

In this project, I am using a website through which I can access the camera, but also need to control the movement of this camera, i.e. I need to control its PTZ. I have no idea how to start, but I would like to control the camera using HTTP because I think it is easier. I searched for some keywords like `Onvif` and `SOAP`, but I found nothing that could really help me.

Does anyone have any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by myself and it is not too difficult. All I need to do is search more about Onvif. As my python is 3 [this link](https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep) was very helpful:

If my python is 2 I would use [this one](https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif).

There are some examples there that help me a lot. For more details about Onvif I also used [this one](https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl).

Now my camera is working very well.

Comment: In it's current state, this is a link only answer. Would you mind expanding on it slightly and give a quick example?